# What happens to Thomas Riker?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-eu

A duplicate of Will Riker that was created in a transporter incident is discovered in the TNG Episode "Second Chances." The next time we see Riker's duplicate is in the DS9 episode "Defiant." We also learn that he is going by his middle name of "Thomas" instead of his first name of "Will" so as to differentiate himself from Will Riker. At the end of the episode Thomas gives himself up to Sisko, and agrees to do hard time for the rest of his life at a Cardassian labor camp.

DS9 "Defiant":

> SISKO [on viewscreen]: The deal is you'll be tried and convicted in a
>   Cardassian court and then sentenced to spend the rest of your life in
>   the Lazon Two labour camp.
>
> RIKER: No death sentence, huh? That must have taken some doing.

After Riker turns the ship over, Major Kira tells him she is going to make sure he gets out.

> RIKER: Transmit the Orias Three sensor logs to the Kraxon, and tell
>   them to prepare to beam me aboard. I'm turning command over to Major
>   Kira. She'll get you back to the Federation. I'm holding you
>   personally responsible to see that these people get a fair trial.
>
> KIRA: I give you my word. We'll get you out of there, Tom. I promise
>   you that.  (Riker kisses Kira.)

What happens to Lt. Thomas Riker after this episode? Does he ever make it to the labor camp? Does he ever get released or rescued? Do we ever hear from him again? If there isn't anything STU then anything EU, writer's notes, or anything else would be appreciated.

Comment: http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Thomas_Riker

Comment: Erm - Thomas Riker wasn't made from a transporter accident in that particular episode; Thomas' existence was found in that episode.  That transporter accident occurred 15 years prior.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### TV Canon

[Canonically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_canon), the events of [DS9: Defiant](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Defiant_(episode)) were the last we know of Tom's life. As you've already mentioned, we see him being shipped off to Lazon Two then he's never mentioned again.

### EU Canon

**There are a considerable number of EU books, comics, and even video games that follow the life of [Thomas Riker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Star_Trek_characters_(N%E2%80%93S)#Thomas_Riker) beyond the end of that episode**.

According to [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page) (the [non-canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_%28fiction%29) Star Trek Wiki) Tom had many adventures ranging from his captivity on Lazon II in a labor camp through to commanding the USS Opaka during the War of the Prophets. You can read all about it here: [Thomas Riker](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Thomas_Riker)

[image]

**Here is a full list of media featuring the further appearances of Tom Riker:**

- **[Star Trek: Deep Space Nine (Malibu Comics) #29-30 – Sole Asylum](http://them0vieblog.com/2014/09/11/star-trek-deep-space-nine-malibu-comics-29-30-sole-asylum-review/)** - Published 1995
- **[Star Trek The Next Generation: Imzadi II Triangle](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/410994.Imzadi_II)** - Published 1999
- **[Star Trek The Next Generation: Double Helix Book 4: Quarantine](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/126065.Quarantine)** - Published 1999
- **[Star Trek: Deep Space Nine: Millennium Omnibus](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/131629.Millennium_Omnibus)** - Published 2000
- **[Star Trek: Deep Space Nine: Dominion Wars for Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine:_Dominion_Wars)** - Published 2001
- **[Star Trek: The Next Generation: Slings and Arrows Book #5: A Weary Life](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6462008-a-weary-life)** - Published 2008
- **[Star Trek Online (Perpetual Entertainment)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Online)** - Windows Published 2010 / Mac Published 2014
- **[Star Trek: Titan: Fallen Gods Mass](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/13093624-fallen-gods)** - Published 2012
- **[Star Trek: The Fall: The Poisoned Chalice](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17570747-the-poisoned-chalice)** - Published 2013